# Error in NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, oracle, nosuchelementexception

Can somebody help me: I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at I6Exc2.menuSelection(I6Exc2.java:28)
at I6Exc2.PersonsWrite(I6Exc2.java:120)
at I6Exc2.menuSelection(I6Exc2.java:43)
at I6Exc2.main(I6Exc2.java:19)
```

This happens when my first input is 3 en my next input is 5. It looks like I did something wrong with closing a scanner? Is somebody able to help me? 
Thanks alot.

```
public class Abc {   
public static Person[] names;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    menuSelection();
}

public static void menuSelection() {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println( "Choose menu item:" + "\n" + "1. Read File"
            + "\n" + "2. Creates nr objects" + "\n" + "3. Write a File"
            + "\n" + "4. Display nr objects" + "\n" + "5. Exit");
    int menuSelection = s.nextInt();

    switch (menuSelection) {
    case 1: System.out.println("Input a name");
    String filePerson = s.next();
    PersonRead(filePerson);
    break;

    case 2: System.out.println("Input nbr of obj");
    int p = s.nextInt();
    PersonsCreate(p);
    break;

    case 3: System.out.println("Input a name");
    String filePersonWrite = s.next();
    PersonWrite(names, filePersonWrite);
    break;

    case 4: PersonsDisplay(names);
    break;

    case 5: System.out.println("Good Bye!");
    s.close();
    break;

    default: System.out.println("Invalid choice");
    menuSelection();
    break;
    }
}

public static Person[] PersonRead (String filePerson) {

    Person[] names2 = names;

    try (FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePerson)) {

        ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(fi);

        names2 = (Person[])os.readObject();

        os.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Person file not found.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File " + filePerson + " does not contains valid Person object");
    }

    names = names2;
    if (names != null) {
        System.out.println("p Person read successfully from file " + filePerson);
    }
    menuSelection();
    return names;
}   

public static Person[] PersonsCreate(int p) {

    names = new Person[p];
    for(int i=0; i < p; i++) {
        names[i] = new Person("Mr. Tim" + i, 20 + i, 'M');
    }

    menuSelection();
    return names;
}

public static void PersonWrite (Person[] Person, String filePerson) {

    if (names != null) {

    try (FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(filePerson)) {

        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);

        os.writeObject(names);

        os.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    System.out.println("p Person written successfully to " + filePerson);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Nothing to write.");
    }

    menuSelection();
}

public static void PersonsDisplay(Person[] Person) {

    for(Person names: Person) {
        System.out.println(names);
    }
    menuSelection();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NoSuchElementException Thrown by the nextElement, if no more tokens are available

[NoSuchElementException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)

check using `hasNextInt()`,

```
if(input.hasNextInt() ){
  int p = s.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed the code (I tried this before): But a new error appears:
    `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.regex.Pattern$Node.study(Pattern.java:3417)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern$Node.study(Pattern.java:3417)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.study(Pattern.java:4631)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern$Node.study(Pattern.java:3417)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern$Node.study(Pattern.java:3417)`
Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @user5424264 i think it is running in infinite loop, causing `StackOverflowError `, pls debug now

Comment: Even when I debug I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Can you post starting point of StackOverFlowError from your Abj.java code?

Comment: I fixed it by putting the switch statement within the if (hasnext) statement. Thanks you all for your help!